# Image appear blank/red when picking an image from gallery in some android phones?

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

The picked image mostly works on all phone devices. But some users reported getting blank/red image when picking an image. I use the code below to pick an image

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Then, I use this code to display the picked image in imageview

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                bitmap= ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(mActivity.getContentResolver(), selectedImageURI));
            } else {
                bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mActivity.getContentResolver(), selectedImageURI);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Glide.with(activity).load(imageUrl)
            .thumbnail(Glide.with(activity).load(R.drawable.loading))
            .error(R.drawable.loading)
            .override(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight())
            .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything common between the users? Devices, OS versions? Chipsets?

Comment: You should use this dependecy to solve this issue because in past i also had same issue in this library helpd me `implementation 'com.github.AnilFurkanOkcun:UWMediaPicker-Android:1.3.3'
` you can give it a try.

Comment: @FcoP. mostly happening on images that have higher image sizes.